# Creating JAX-WS Web Service with POJO business objects project

Tags: jax-ws, pojo

I have a service that I am writing where I use POJO's to kind of act as a go between my stateless session bean and my Java Bean webservice in addition to my JPA project.  However, whenever I attempt to generate JAX-WS service via the Wizard, I get an error which basically tells me that the Business objects aren't in the build path of the new Webservices project.  Which they wouldn't be, because I haven't built the project yet.
My question would be how can I get the wizard to put my POJO's in the build path so I don't get that exception?

Comment: What is the JAX-WS runtime or the Application Server?

Comment: The application server is WAS 7.0.

Comment: Have you tried without the wizard? Does the service is deployed on the server?

Comment: I am attempting to learn how to do this without the wizard.  I actually am trying to learn how to turn Stateless session beans into a Web service.

Comment: Just put under the `@Stateless` the `@WebService` annotation and enjoy!

Comment: Wish it were that simple.  I tried, and WID is throwing exceptions

Comment: @DmainEvent what exactly is the exception?